# Unable to change default route-Rhel 5.9

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel5, route

am trying to change default to route to eth2 my present rout -n o/p--

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.235.4.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
10.235.3.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
10.235.2.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.X.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth3
default         10.235.4.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth3
```

IP ro sh - output

```
# ip ro sh
10.235.4.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.235.4.21
10.235.3.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.235.3.21
10.235.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.235.2.21
169.x.0.0/16 dev eth3  scope link
default via 10.235.4.1 dev eth3
```

What i am trying to do is

```
> Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.235.4.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
10.235.3.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
10.235.2.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.x.0.0       *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth3
default         10.235.2.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
```

I tryed different ways 
a> add "gatewaydev=eth2" in/etc/sysconfig/network.
b> added route eth2 by command and deleted eth3 route entry.

after service network restart it going back to first output.

help me
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just add/replace default gateway ip address to/in the /etc/sysconfig/network

```
GATEWAY=10.235.2.1
```

And then restart the newtwork service

```
# service network restart
```

Comment: I have as gateway=eth0 but still not working

Comment: add output of the # ip ro sh to your question

Answer (score 1):

You must have address from `10.235.2.0` network on `eth2` first, then you can change `GATEWAY=` value.

Comment: Yea , I have . I added eth0 interrface in dhcp server which is 10.235.0.2 scope

Answer (score 1):

Open /etc/sysconfig/network file:

```
#vi  /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Setup GATEWAY={Router-IP}

```
GATEWAY=10.235.2.1
```

You need to restart networking service:

```
# /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: It is working fine wirth i keep gateway address as 10.235.2.1 , but iwant go by device not by gateway-ip

Comment: Run command setup then go to menu network configuration and select the ethernet card(NIC) which you want to configure and setup gateway ip there.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to add the gateway to the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX config file for the appropriate interface, eg:

```
BOOTPROTO=none
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
SLAVE=no
IPADDR=10.20.30.40
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=10.20.30.1
USERCTL=no
BROADCAST=10.20.30.255
```

I tend *not* to put it in /etc/sysconfig/network, though you certainly can. I do a lot of really complex bonding configurations, and it makes it easier if all the files are in one place.

If you do it like I do it, DO NOT declare the gateway interface in other IFCFG files. It will read them in order, resetting the gateway every time, and you won't get the expected behaviour.